# Problem with jquery double click in google console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I would like to doubleclick a cell in an ag grid so that I can enter data using puppeteer. I am first trying to get the code to work in google console.

If I enter `` $(`div[row-index="8"]`)[1].childNodes[0].innerText ``
the console returns the correct cell value "$100"

If I enter `` $(`div[row-index="8"]`)[1].childNodes[0].dblclick() ``

I get Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[1].childNodes[0].dblclick is not a function
at :1:42

Why won't double click work?

Comment: Because that is not JQuery

Comment: `dblclick()` is a jQuery method, not native JS. You need to use `dispatchEvent()`. See the duplicates